# traverse a string char by char javascript

Tags: javascript, charat

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) { 
    var letter =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j',
    'k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];

    var newstr = "";
    for (var i = 0; i<str.length; i++){
        if (str.charAt(i).toLowerCase() in letter){
            newstr += "M";
        }
        else{
            newstr += "X";
        }
    }

return newstr; 

}
```

If str is "Argument goes here" it returns XXXXXXXXX. WHy doesn't it return MMMMMMMMMM?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you do not look up an entry in an array with `in`. use `indexOf()` to find the position of an array entry. `indexOf()` will return the position or `-1` if no entry is found.

```
for (var i = 0; i<str.length; i++){
    var strChar = str.charAt(i).toLowerCase();

    if ( letter.indexOf(strChar) >= 0 ) {
        newstr += "M";
    }
…
```

Comment: And if you could explain your answer now?

Comment: @FelixKling var why? what do you mean?

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking when you just posted the code.

Comment: does it make sense to you now?

Answer (score 4):

The [**`in` operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) returns `true` if the object has a property with that **name**, not with that *value*.

An array is basically an object with numeric properties. I.e. the **indexes** are the property names of the object. It basically looks like this:

```
var letters = {
  0: 'a',
  1: 'b',
  ...
  length: ...
};
```

So in your case the condition will only be `true` if `str.charAt(i).toLowerCase()` returns a number between `0` and `letter.length` (and since `charAt` only returns one character, it can only be `0-9`).

Example:

```
> var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
> 'a' in letters // array doesn't have a property 'a'
false
> 0 in letters   // array has a property 0 (it's the first element)
true
```

So since, `"Argument goes here"` doesn't contain any digits, the `in` condition will always be `false` and that's why you get `XXXXXX...` as result.

See the question "[How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/237104/218196)" for testing the existence of an element in an array.

---

FWIW, to make the `in` operator work, you would have to create an object of the form:

```
var letters = {
  'a': true,
  'b': true,
  // ...
};
```

but that's a bit cumbersome to write.

Comment: so I should use .contains?

Comment: there is no contains.

Comment: @dreamlab: I never said there is.

Comment: i know you didn't. but @mikeandike didn't understand.

Comment: Btw, downvoter, if anything is wrong with my answer, let me know, I'm happy to correct it.

Comment: Nothing worth of a down vote far as I can see. What do you think @dreamlab?

Comment: in depth explanation of the topic. only thing i would suggest to edit is the "array.contains" title so that @mikeandike's assumption can not be made.

Comment: @dreamlab: That's the title of the other question. I simply copied the link, it gets autoconverted by the parser. But I can make it clearer that this is a link to a question.

Comment: oh, i see. than the title is bad. maybe just link without the title ;)

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to offer a side view, another way handle what I think you intent to do by using **Regular Expressions** with something like:

`"test2".replace(/[a-z]/gi,"M").replace(/[^M]/g,"X") //Outputs "MMMMX"`

`String.replace` will replace an string that contains letters from `[a-z]` the `i` at the end of the expression means case insensitive. g means will search for all possible matches and not just the first match. In the second expression `[^M]` this `^` means negation so anything that is not an `M` will be replaced with `X`.

There is another way in which we implement a custom function within the `String.replace` using Regular Expressions and it can be implemented like this:

```
"test2".replace(/([a-z])|([^a-z])/gi,
     function(m,g1, g2){ 
            return g1 ? "M" : "X";  
     });
```

In regular expression parenthesis creates groups and | means or in this expression `([a-z])|([^a-z])` there 2 groups one with letters from a-z and the other which means everything that is not `a-z` with the replace function we asked only for group `g1` if it is group 1 is `M` otherwise is an `X`.

Another cool thing you could do is add this function to all your string by prototyping it like:

```
String.prototype.traverse = function(){ return this.replace(/([a-z])|([^a-z])/gi,function(m,g1){ return g1 ? "M" : "X"  });}
```

Then it can be used as simple as: `"test1".traverse();`